# How can I promote a child website?

Tags: website-design, interface, web, advertisement

We have 2 websites - let's call them website A and B.

Website A is about event management and website B is about sustainable events, so they are very similar, albeit with slightly different themes/goals.

In essence, website B is the child of website A.

How can I show on website B that it is powered by website A?

How can I promote website A through website B without having to put in obvious ads/banners/pop-ups?

Comment: No idea if this is the case or not, but if "_sustainable events_" means focusing on eco-friendly, low carbon-footprints etc., and the main website appeared to promote events with no concern for their environmental impact, you might not _want_ too close a link between the two.

Comment: Maybe I should be a bit more clear: the sustainable events page tries to facilitate events that are focused on sustainability, but the original event management platform facilitates on all kind of events. We just want to smoothly show that the sustainability platform is made based on the general event management platform (it actually focuses on hackathons, graduate programs etc. so they not not sustainable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest adding a link at the top with words like "Powered by ". Or maybe just "Looking for other events. Check out ".

You can also ask the team to change URL of child website to something like "www.parentsite.com/childsite". Keep the existing domain "www.childsite.com" and redirect it to the new URL. This way, every time user search for child website, parent website will be listed in the results as well. Obviously this is not a UX thing and more of a SEO tip, but I think it will be very useful for you.

Comment: That's what we pretty much decided on - to have 'powered by A' near B's logo. But was thinking if there are any other novel ways. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That's why the SEO tip. Although it is useful only if your users search for the website rather than directly typing the url in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to look at content marketing strategies for this. Maybe design some landing pages and direct traffic to it. But you could also think about how this website shows it's child websites, stack exchange has it's global nav and the child websites sit inside of them.

Comment: The problem here is that we only have 1 child website while stack exchange has plenty. Not sure how we could approach that

Comment: @Velionis 1 child website is still a child website. You can still use the StackExchange style. It will also be helpful in future when you decide to add more child websites.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how much you want to highlight the relationship you could use one of several approaches:

- Do like stack exchange: add a link to the child site on the parent and vice-versa.
- On the parent site: Add a section "built with our platform / facilitated by us / our events" and showcase / link to some / all the events, with a link to the child site. Or just write a blurb about the child site and add a link.
- On the child site: simply add a footer "built / promoted by / with" linking to the parent.

Comment: StackExchange is a very good example of this. Keeping a consistent design theme yet with subtle characteristic changes is key here.